# angular animation - changing the state without user interaction

Tags: angular, typescript, animation, highlight

Hope someone can help me please - see this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/basic-highlight-animation)

What I want to achieve is a simple highlight effect where an element's background flashes a colour briefly and then fades back to FFF.

There are two buttons there just to show the different transitions, but what I want is to join them together in one method to make it flash and fade.

I also want keep the animation separate from the component because I'll want to re-use it.

So to change the states I thought I could just set the value of highlightState in form.component.ts to true, and then immediately set it back to false. Even though the two statements would execute almost immediately, I thought the longer transition from true to false would give the effect that I wanted. What actually happens is that I can't see anything

I tried using `setTimeout()`, and keeping the transitions the same in highlight.ts (just using <=> to toggle the states), but all that happens then is the highlight stays on.

I know that it's basic and I'm disappointed that I can't get it to work, but if you can help I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to use keyframe animations. I think you missed that the animation should appear if element is in any state. For that `*` is used.

Here, `* <=> *` indicates that I don't care in what state element is, just perform animation.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/basic-highlight-animation-g9v864?file=src%2Fapp%2Fanimations%2Fhighlight.ts)

**highlight.ts**

```js
export const highlight = trigger('highlight', [transition('* <=> *', useAnimation(
  animation(
    animate(
      '500ms 0s',
      keyframes([
        style({ background: '#FFFFFF' }),
        style({ background: '#ff0000' }),
        style({ background: '#FFFFFF' })
      ])
    )
  )
))]);
```

Comment: Ah I see - thank you so much. I've updated the stackBlitz.

Comment: Ah I see - thank you so much. I like this approach better and I've updated the stackBlitz to make it a bit clearer what I want to do.

Because I want the colour to fade slower than it appears, I've used offset to control the length of each animation.

Why do you need three keyframes though? Is it because of what you were saying about not caring what state the element is in when the animation is called?

Comment: Yes. It means that dont care the element current condition. Just start from fff goto ff00ff and then come back to fff in 500ms. Last fff is needed as you want to make background fff again. Hope this makes sense. :)